# What is the part of speech of quantifiers? Adjective or determiner?

Tags: quantifiers

> Quantifiers are **adjectives and adjectival phrases** that give approximate or specific answers to the questions "How much?" and "How many?" [Education First](http://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/quantifiers/)

> We use the quantifiers much, many, a lot of, lots of to talk about quantities, amounts and degree. We can use them with a noun (as a **determiner**) or without a noun (as a **pronoun**). [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers)

What is the part of speech of "quantifiers"? Are they *adjectives* or *determiner*? Or both together?

Comment: This Education First site sounds bad. I won't recommend it to any learner. :(

Comment: I think you confused _adjective_ as a _part of speech_ and _adjevtive_ as the role that a word or phrase play in a sentence i.e. function. For example, _car_ is a _noun_ but in the phrase _car factory_ it _acts as_ an adjective since it gives information about the noun preceding it giving more information about the noun.

Comment: M.A.R. is right. Steer clear of Education First.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no universal convention on the parts of speech in English, except perhaps that linguists dislike the term *part of speech* (they prefer terms like *lexical category* or *word class*). Consider the following:

- Under the traditional model, as for example given in Joseph Priestly's 1761 *[The Rudiments of English Grammar](https://archive.org/details/rudimentsenglis00priegoog)*, every word in a sentence could supposedly be classified as one of exactly eight types: noun, pronoun, verb, adjective, adverb, conjunction, preposition, or interjection. This model is deprecated by linguists, but still widely taught.
- The magisterial 2002 *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), by Rodney Huddleston and Geoffrey Pullum, divides conjunctions into two classes as well as elevates the derminer, giving noun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, determinative, subordinator, coordinator, and interjection as the word classes.
- Dave Willis, co-author of the Collins COBUILD English Course, uses noun, verb, adjective, adverb, preposition, determiner, quantifier, and conjunction.
- The Routledge English Grammar by Roger Berry lists noun, adjective, adverb, (main) verb, pronoun, determiner, preposition, auxiliary verb, and conjunction.

The case has been made that determiners should be considered a separate class of words, just as pronouns are distinct from nouns. After all, it is a closed set of words which behaves differently from adjectives: they cannot be stacked, they cannot be graded, they cannot be intensified. They have a distinctive purpose in a sentence. Modern textbooks seem to agree, including all three noted above. Note that the Education First website also recognizes this distinction in the organization of its site.

Comment: determiners ... cannot be intensified?  -- What about biased quantifiers (many/much few/little) as in "very much", "so few", etc.